# Is there a way to create filenames in python?

Tags: python

I have filenames of the format:

```
Unix3145_report.txt 
Unix5694_report.txt
Unix3452_report.txt
Unix1232_report.txt
Unix5492_report.txt
```

The difference is only four digit numbers. I am reading all these files and converting text inside it to other file.

Currently I do argument parsing from command line and give the complete filename.

Is there a way, I can create filenames in my script itself inserting just the number taken from user? something like `os.join.path` for creating filepath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.path.join` is for joining paths , not creating filenames.

A filename would be a simple string , you can create it as you create any other string. Example -

```
num = 3145              #This can be the number inputted from user or some other place
filename = "Unix{}_report.txt".format(num)
print(filename)
>>> Unix3145_report.txt
```

Then after this you can use `os.path.join` if required to create the complete path to file.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the string

```
fileName = "Unix"+userInput+"_report.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is with the `%`-formatting

```
filename = 'Unix%s_report.txt' % num
```

- Aside: instead of `%s` (for string), you can use `%d` to make sure that `num` is a digit type